# "File -X: does not exist" message from ipy.exe in Windows PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, ironpython

If I type this line in an MS-DOS command prompt window:

```
ipy -X:ColorfulConsole
```

IronPython starts up as expected with the colorful console option enabled. However, if I type the same line in Windows PowerShell I get the message:

```
File -X: does not exist
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
ipy '-X:ColorfulConsole'
```

Or whatever quoting mechanism is supported in Windows PowerShell - the shell is splitting your argument.

Typing

```
ipy -X: ColorfulConsole
```

in MS-DOS command prompt window returns the same response:

`File -X: does not exist`.

Comment: Thanks. Putting the option in single quotes fixed the problem.